# ¿Cómo funciona este código?

Tags: javascript, array, string, prototipos

Tengo una serie de dudas con este código:

```
String.prototype.times = function(count) {
  return count < 1 ? '' : new Array(count).join(this);
}
```

Lo que hace es duplicar un `string` las veces que se pida como por ejemplo:

```js
String.prototype.times = function(count) {
  return count < 1 ? '' : new Array(count + 1).join(this);
}

var a = "Duplicame! ".times(4);

console.log(a);
```

Mis dudas son:

> 1. ¿Por qué debe sumarle + 1?
> 2. ¿Por qué `join(this)`, si se supone que `join` es para determinar cómo va a unir el `array` en un `string`?
> 3. Esto devuelve un `array` con `count` valores, y según lo que sé, devolvería un `array` indefinido con `count` valores, entonces... ¿por
>      qué me devuelve `count` strings, en vez de devolverme la cadena y el
>      `array` retornado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las respuestas a tus preguntas:

1. Le suma 1 porque el método `join` une los elementos del `array` con el valor pasado por argumento y devuelve una cadena resultante. Si quieres obtener como resultado la cadena pasada por argumento repetida N veces, el `array` sobre el cual el método `join` se ejecuta debe tener N+1 elementos para que pueda haber N huecos entre los elementos unidos con el valor del argumento (el cual quieres repetir N veces).
2. Por eso mismo. Como `join` es un método para unir en un `string` los elementos de un `array` usando como «pegamento» el argumento pasado a `join`, si el `array` tiene N+1 elementos, el pegamento para unirlos se usa N veces. Y si además los elementos del `array` no están definidos (`undefined`), significa que la cadena resultante sólo va a estar formada por el argumento pasado a `join` repetido N veces (el pegamento pegado N veces para unir N+1 elementos sin definir, es decir, unir nada). Creas un `string` formado sólo por el pegamento N veces.
3. La última pregunta no la entiendo muy bien, pero al ejecutar el código, el método `times` funciona correctamente: duplica la cadena sobre la que es llamada un número de veces.

Comment: La ultima pregunta creo que era una de las mas importante, me refiero a que lo que HACE este codigo es duplicar una string N + 1 veces, pero como es posible? esto me retorna un nuevo array de .length de N + 1 , peor entonces no me deberia devolver una string y un array de N +1 de longitud?(length)

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Entonces creo que queda respondida en la explicación de las otras dos preguntas.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian ¿Entiendes el uso operador ternario `?:` dentro de la función, la creación del `Array` y el porqué de la definición de la función `times` dentro del objeto prototipo de `String`?

Comment: El prototipo de string y una forma de if/else pero no entiendo mucho esta..

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Al añadir la función `times` en el prototipo de `String` permites que sea llamada como método para cualquier objeto de tipo `String`. El operador ternario `?:` es una forma de escribir como expresión una sentencia `if-else`. Y `new Array(count+1)` crea un array de `count+1` elementos de tipo `undefined`.